# http testing - faking chunked response at transport layer

Tags: go

I want to override the roundTrip of the transport layer of an http response such that I edit the chunks of a response as it comes in.

I'm looking for a way I can unit test the chunked response coming in. Does anyone have any libraries or any leads on best practice as to how to do this.

Comment: You could use the `net/http` package's internal chunked reader for testing.

Comment: what do you  mean by chunked response? can you give an example of a func/method you want to unit test?